# Creating a function to open a new folder each time an image is uploaded

Tags: django

I want to create a function where everytime a user uploads an image a new folder is created with their username (designer_name) and associate each title to each uploaded Image is that possible?

If it is what is the best way to do it?

The model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    design = models.ImageField(
        blank=False, null=True, upload_to='new designs')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("score:post-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can define a function that specifies the place where the image should be uploaded to, and set it to the [**`upload_to=…`** parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    def upload_design_to(self, filename):
        return f'{self.designername}/{self.title}/{filename}'

    designer_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    design = models.ImageField(
        blank=False, null=True, upload_to=upload_design_to)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("score:post-detail", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

> **Note**: A `ForeignKey` does *not* store the string representation (or name) of the
>   referenced object in the column, it stores the primary key of the record it
>   references in a column with an  `_id` suffix to a `ForeignKey` field. Therefore
>   `ForeignKey`s usually do *not* end with a `_name` suffix. You might want to
>   consider renaming the <s>`designer_name`</s> field to `designer`.

Comment: thank you... just in the return of the function {self.title} ..... thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
def new designs(instance, filename):
    file_path = 'blog/{author_id}/{title}-{filename}'.format(
        author_id=str(instance.author.id), title=str(instance.title), filename=filename)
    return file_path
```